# Mysql deployment deleting my database in kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, docker-desktop

I created a mysql deployment where I connect with other pods. I do remote access to create the database and tables but I saw that at some point in the mysql lifecycle it deletes my database how can I make it not deleted?

I thought about creating a static pod but I don't know if this solves my problem, it follows my structure below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: rafaelribeirosouza86/shopping:myql
        name: mysql
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
#      secret:
#        secretName: mysql-pass
#        items:
#        - key: password
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
#  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 20Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
```

Does anyone have an idea how I can resolve this?

Comment: I'd normally expect the cluster to create the PersistentVolume for you.  A `hostPath:` volume isn't especially reliable since it refers to a fixed path but not a specific node, so if your Pod is recreated on a different node you won't see that content.  A StatefulSet might be a better match for this use case than a Deployment.

Comment: do you think a StatefulSet would be ideal for my case?

Comment: It tends to be a better match for stateful workloads like databases, yes.

Comment: I'll test it and then I'll give you a feedback thank you